# How can I display my HTML file in browser? I have already successfully connected the server and client

Tags: python, http, server

As I wrote on title, I have already successfully connected the server and client.
But the client can't display the HTML file.
I checked file path and send function. But can't find any fault.
When running the code, the code runs normally until `connectionSocket.close()`.
But browser can't display the HTML file, just blank.
So, I checked the details and I found that `connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i].encode())` send values, 1 or 3.
I don't know the reason but I'm sure that that is the cause.
Please give me your insight.

```
from socket import *


serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

# Prepare a sever socket
TCPPort = 8000
BufferSize = 1024
serverSocket.bind((host, TCPPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)

while True:
    # Establish the connection
    print('Ready to serve...')
    (connectionSocket,addr) = serverSocket.accept()
    print('connectionSocket is:',connectionSocket)
    try:
        message = connectionSocket.recv(BufferSize)
        print('message is:',message)
        #filename = message.split()[1]
        #print('filename is:', filename)
        f = open('\HTML.html','r',encoding='UTF-8')
        outputdata = f.read()

        # Send one HTTP header line into socket
        connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'.encode('UTF-8'))

        # Send the content of the requested file to the client
        for i in range(0,len(outputdata)):
            connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i].encode())
        connectionSocket.close()

    except IOError:
        connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'.encode('UTF-8'))
        connectionSocket.send("<html><head></head><body><h1>404 Not Found</h1></body></html> ".encode('UTF-8'))
        # Close client socket
        connectionSocket.close()

serverSocket.close()
```

Comment: Why is tagged node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make **your** server to respond by the HTTP protocol. In HTTP there are 2 newlines between headers and body and you need to send both together:

```
from socket import *

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

# Prepare a sever socket
TCPPort = 8000
BufferSize = 1024
serverSocket.bind(('127.0.0.1', TCPPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)

while True:
    # Establish the connection
    print('Ready to serve...')
    (connectionSocket, addr) = serverSocket.accept()
    print('connectionSocket is:', connectionSocket)
    try:
        message = connectionSocket.recv(BufferSize)
        print('message is:', message)
        #filename = message.split()[1]
        #print('filename is:', filename)
        #f = open('\HTML.html','r',encoding='UTF-8')
        outputdata = "<html><body>foo</body></html>"

        # Send one HTTP header line into socket
        response = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nConnection: close\n\n' + outputdata
        connectionSocket.send(response.decode())

        # Send the content of the requested file to the client
        connectionSocket.close()

    except IOError:
        connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'.encode('UTF-8'))
        connectionSocket.send(
            "<html><head></head><body><h1>404 Not Found</h1></body></html> ".
            encode('UTF-8')
        )
        # Close client socket
        connectionSocket.close()

serverSocket.close()
```

Test, using: `curl -X GET http://localhost:8000`

Out:

```
<html><body>foo</body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Thanks to your help, I can understand more about socket programming. Have a good day :)